Customize Log a Call
Good day, everyone! I would just like to ask if it is possible to add a picklist field in the Log a Call action? 
I am looking for a way to use a picklist instead of free text as it is more neat to see. All of your insights will be much appreciated.
Thank you!

This is possible by editing the layout for the Log a Call Global Action.
To edit this, you can navigate to Setup > Global Actions > Layout (next to the Log a Call action). From there you can edit which fields are visible when users select the action.
If you are going to use a custom picklist field, you'll need to create that first on the Activity object and make sure you have given access to that field for the appropriate users for it to be available.

Thanks for this sir. It worked! Have a nice day ahead.
